# length of a zero dimensional sheaf on a $K3$ surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $K3$ surface  over $\mathbb C$ and $\mathcal F$ be a $0$ dimensional sheaf on it.

Then is the following true: length $\mathcal F =h^0(X , \mathcal F)$ ?

Here I hope that length $\mathcal F $ means length of the closed subscheme given by its support i.e $h^0(Z , \mathcal O_Z)$ where $Z =supp(\mathcal F)$.

Can somebody give a hint on how to prove it or may be some reference.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: The answer tot the first is yes. The length of $F$ is not the length of $H^0(Z,O_Z)$ in general.

Comment: @Mohan, then whats the actual definition of length of $\mathcal F$?Could you give me a reference which discusses about the equality

Comment: Any coherent zero dimensional sheaf $F$ can be filtered by finitely many sheaves of the form $\mathbb{C}(x)$ for points $x$ and the length of this filtration (which is independent of the filtration) is called the length of $F$.

Comment: Thanks@Mohan.Is this the definition for any sheaf irrespective of its dimension?Can you refer me to a source in the literature?

Comment: I do not understand when you say irrespective of the dimension. Only zero dimensional coherent sheaves have such a finite filtration. Most algebra/algebraic geometry will have the definition, search for finite length modules/sheaves.